# How do i enable the firefox xbap plugin

Tags: wpf, firefox, xbap

Firefox recently blacklisted the plugin that allows xbaps to work in firefox

This is a huge problem for me as one of my companies enterprise products is a web application that makes use of an xbap and must work in firefox.

Does anyone know if there is an update to the blacklisted plugin or if it is possible to overwrite the blacklist and use the plugin anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Windows Presentation Foundation plugin is no longer blocklisted.](http://shaver.off.net/diary/2009/10/19/update-on-the-net-framework-assistant-and-windows-presentation-foundation-plugin-blocking-from-this-weekend/)  Are you sure it's still blocked?

Comment: Thanks for that, upon further investigation Ive discovered that the framework assistant plugin has been enabled but the wpf plugin appears to have been removed completely and i cant for the life of me find where to download it again :(

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to place the NPWPF.dll in the Firefox Plugin folder.
That works perfectly.

You can find the NPWPF.dll file in :

> [WINDIR]\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Windows Presentation Foundation